# zsh script testing ssh successfully or not

Tags: shell-script, ssh, zsh, openssh

I have a zsh script `script.zsh server-name-here` that have one argument, I need to test ssh to that `server-name-here`, and if success continue doing something, if not exit script.

How can we achieve that?

Or I can do with this line in zsh:

`ssh user@$1 'exit' &> /dev/null
if (( $? )); then
...`

Answer (score 0):

You can check if `ssh` is successful directly in an `if`, like so:

```
if ssh maulinglawns@<host> 'exit'; then
    echo "ssh success. Do stuff here..."
else
    echo "ssh failed"
    exit 1
fi
```

Note: tested with Bash, but should work on Zsh as well.